# why do i get 0 instead the result of calculation x - y and x/y in C

Tags: c, global-variables

In this code I thought I would get the result of calculation x / y and x - y but the program shows 0 for i and j. What is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

float calculate(float, float);
float i, j;

int main()
{
    float a, b;

    printf("Enter two numbers:\n");
    scanf("%f%f", &a, &b);
    printf("\nThe results are: %f  %f  %f\n", calculate(a, b), i, j);

    return 0;
}

float calculate(float x, float y)
{
    float r;

    r = x * y;
    i = x / y;
    j = x - y;
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is *undefined behavior*, when you call the calculate() function within the same printf and i as well as j are calculated within that printf (same function). By the way, it is not a good idea to use global variables ( i, j ) ... For test purpose only, you could calculate() before the next printf of i and j.

You can test that behavior with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float calculate(float, float);
float i, j;
int main()
{
    float a, b;

    printf("Enter two numbers:\n");
    scanf("%f%f", &a, &b);
    printf("\nThe results are: %f", calculate(a, b));
    printf("    %f    %f\n", i, j);

    return 0;
}

float calculate(float x, float y)
{
    float r;

    r = x * y;
    i = x / y;
    j = x - y;
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to the parsing, reference, and execution order of the arguments in printf function. The printf function uses the arguments right-to-left direction. You can easily check the order through below codes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float calculate(float, float);
float i, j;

int main()
{
    float a, b;

    printf("Enter two numbers:\n");
    scanf("%f%f", &a, &b);
    //printf("\nThe results are: %f  %f  %f\n", calculate(a, b), i, j);
    printf("\nThe results are: %f  %f  %f\n", i, j, calculate(a, b));

    return 0;
}

float calculate(float x, float y)
{
    float r;

    r = x * y;
    i = x / y;
    j = x - y;
    return r;
}
```